# How to select multiple existing column names and group it into 1 column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

Im using posgresql. How may I group the column name into one column and its value in another column from an existing table? Then use it to create a temporary table?

Existing table:

```
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|  col_a  |   col_b  |  col_c  |   col_d  |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|       1 |        2 |       3 |        4 |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Temporary Table:

```
+----------+----------+
|categories|   value  |
+----------+----------+
|   col_a  |        1 |  
|   col_b  |        2 |
|   col_c  |        3 | 
|   col_d  |        4 | 
+----------+----------+
```

The following is the sql statement to generate the temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table myTable_temp
(
    categories Varchar (50),
    value float8
);
```

But I am still stuck at trying to group the specific column names into one column and bring its value on the other column but still link it together.

Comment: Just a hint you need to start looking for PIVOT SQL, It might help you.

Comment: @MuhammadHisham: it's actually an UNPIVOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is also known as UNPIVOT and can be done like this in Postgres:

```
select up.*
from the_table
  cross join lateral (
    values 
      ('col_a', col_a),
      ('col_b', col_b),
      ('col_c', col_c),
      ('col_d', col_d)
  ) as up(category, value);
```

Note that this only works if all columns have the same data type.

If you don't mind losing the data type (or if the columns have different types and you need to cast them to `text` anyway), you can make this dynamic by using JSON functions:

```
select up.*
from the_table tt
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(tt)) as up;
```

If you know all values can be cast to the same type, you can use:

```
select up.category, 
       up.value::float
from the_table tt
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(tt)) as up(category, value);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SHOY36906

---

If you need to match the "value" column to the original primary key of the table, you could do something like this (assuming the primary key is named `id`)

```
select tt.id, up.*
from the_table tt
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(tt) - 'id') as up(category, value)
order by tt.id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MSXD50860

Answer (score 1):

You just want a union

```
   Select "col_a" , col_a as "value" from 
   table 
   union
   Select  "col_b" , col_b as "value"  from 
   table
   union
   Select  "col_c" , col_c as "value"  from 
    table 
    union
   Select  "col_d" , col_d as "value"   from 
    table
```